# Search for specific patterns in Splunk cloud platform

Tags: splunk

I am new to splunk and am trying to perform incident analysis of a compromised domain controller security event logs. I am using the free trial version of splunk cloud platform and ingested the csv data and let splunk automatically create the indexes. The attack is a brute force attack and it seems that some malicious user tried to find the members of a remote desktop user group in the AD.

[image: Splunk Search events results]
I am attaching a screenshot of my current splunk search result and the further filter that I want to use [ highlighted in black ]. As you will see in the current search result, it is listing many such events, but I am only interested in certain events, where under the Subject section, the account names have values other than a given set of names (say ID4$, Admin, Harvester etc.). How can that be achieved?

Comment: Can't you just add a `NOT CASE(ID4$) NOT CASE(Admin) NOT CASE(Harvester)` to the search?  If those terms can appear other places and you need to have the Account Name part there then what about adding `| search NOT "Account Name:           ID4$" NOT "Account Name:           Admin" NOT "Account Name:           Harvester"` to the search?  If you have more complicatd stuff you can use a `where` statement with like or match to allow wilcards and regex - you could add `| where !match(_raw,"Account Name: *ID4\$") AND !match(_raw,"Account Name: *Admin") AND !match(_raw,"Account Name: *Harvester")`

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd *strongly* recommend you take the free courses available from Splunk: https://www.splunk.com/en_us/training.html?sort=Newest&filters=filterGroup1FreeCourses

Second, you need to look for field=value pairs in your data

Like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp fieldA=valA fieldB=valB* fieldC=valC
| stats values(host) as host values(valB) by fieldA fieldC
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @warren's answer, you need to extract fields before they can be searched.  Then you can filter based on those fields.

```
index=foo source=bar 
| rex field=EXTRA_FIELD_6 "Account Name:\s*(?<Account_Name>\w+)
| search NOT Account_Name IN ("ID4$", "Admin", "Harvester")
```